# How do you refresh a page, and the continue to perform actions afterwards?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently writing a javascript program, and I'd like to refresh a web page, and then proceed to call a function that modifies the newly refreshed page afterwards.

However, whenever I call location.reload(), the page ends up performing the actions prior to the refresh, despite the fact that I've placed them after the refresh in the code. How would I go about getting the page to form actions after a refresh?

Comment: You'll have to put that code in the *new page*. Nothing the old page does after a `location.reload()` will affect the new page. That's just how it works.

Comment: Can you provide us with some example code and give us some context as to what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: `location.reload()` is non blocking so it is executed before it is finished reloading

Comment: And..whats the point of refreshing the page? What changes when the page reloads? Have you heard of ajax?

Answer (score 3):

You can cheat to do this using sessionStorage:

```js
//in some function:
sessionStorage.setItem('onReload', 'doFn1');
location.reload();
```

```js
//elsewhere, to be called on page load:
if(sessionStorage.getItem('onReload') === 'doFn1') {
    sessionStorage.setItem('onReload', '');
        // do your code
}
```

Ultimately, though, this isn't a good practice. Why are you reloading the page? You can probably accomplish what you want *without* a page reload.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't continue executing after page reload, it starts fresh.

If you really need to refresh the page and then start a specific action you'll have to have to have some way to tell your code to start from where it left off.

One way to solve the problem is to add a hash to the url, which will serve as a flag to continue execution.

```
window.location.href += "#continueScript";
location.reload();
```

then in your function check for the hash.

```
if(window.location.hash == "#continueScript") {
    continueMyScript();
};
```